# Why my unexpected outcome just making a link?

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink

Ive got this obviously wrong output when trying such a simple thing as making a link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/apps/a%E2%80%8Bpplication.php?id=164355773607%E2%80%8B006
```

Of course the link should be

```
http://www.facebook.com/apps/a​pplication.php?id=164355773607​006
```

and it's also corrrect in the code:

```
<a class="nobk" href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/a​pplication.php?id=164355773607​006"><img src="/_/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Kool Business" width="50" height="50"/></a>
```

My page with the bug is koolbusiness.com. Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the spaces in "a pplication.php" and the id value.

Comment: I'm sure it's something like you say but where? I don't see anything like "a pplication.php" anywhere in source or output still that seems to be what's going on

Comment: You say the link should be `http://www.facebook.com/apps/a​pplication.php?id=164355773607​006` when in fact it should be `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=164355773607006` -- you had two unwanted spaces in the middle of the URL.

Comment: Success! The spaces were "hidden" and invisble to the eye but appeared when stepping through the source and replacing the parts with new characters. Strange that the source didn't display the spaces i.e. the status bar didn't have the space but now it's anyhow fixed. Thank you for insisting.